# ReactJS - Getting JSX to recognize a props value as an imported class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello and thank you for your time on this.

React & JS newbie here.

I am working with two bits of code:

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; im
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Modals from "./Modal";
import EditorComponent from './Editor';

ReactDOM.render(<Modals childComponent="<EditorComponent />" />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Modal.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import EditorComponent from './Editor';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

 class Modals extends Component {


    render() {

        return (
            <div className="static-modal">
              <Modal.Dialog>
                <Modal.Header>
                  <Modal.Title>Journey onward...</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body>{this.props.childComponent}</Modal.Body>

                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button>Close</Button>
                  <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal.Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Modals;
```

**Question**

If I was to replace `{this.props.childComponent}` in **Modal.js** with `<EditorComponent />`, the class is successfully called. However when passed from **index.js**, as in the code above, the Modal is called successfully but with just "`<EditorComponent />`" in the body content as plain text.

I am unable to understand why this is happening. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use children instead of doing like this. What you are passing here is string so you are getting the plain text there. so you need to change a ReactDOM.render to this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Modals><EditorComponent/></Modals>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and change your `modal.js` to this:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
import EditorComponent from './Editor';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

 class Modals extends Component {


    render() {

        return (
            <div className="static-modal">
              <Modal.Dialog>
                <Modal.Header>
                  <Modal.Title>Journey onward...</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>

                <Modal.Body>{this.props.children}</Modal.Body>

                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button>Close</Button>
                  <Button bsStyle="primary">Save changes</Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal.Dialog>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Modals;
```

or else just pass it as component instead of string:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Modals childComponent={<EditorComponent />} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Much appreciate the detailed response and clarification. Passing it as a component is what I needed to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You were passing EditorComponent as a string, not as an instance of EditorComponent component.

```
childComponent={<EditorComponent />}
```

**Update**

Option 2:

You don't need to pass EditorComponent as an instance, you can pass it by reference. I actually prefer this approach, but it depends on the situation.

index:

```
childComponent={EditorComponent}
```

modal:

```
const {EditorComponent } = this.props

<Modal.Body><EditorComponent /></Modal.Body>
```

Comment: Much appreciated. This is exactly what I needed.